# How do you know which parameters are needed for an XHR request?

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests

I'm using requests to get a json file from http://fplstatistics.co.uk/Home/Events, and to do this I'm using the typical

```
response = requests.get(url, params=params, headers=headers)
```

Here `params` is a dictionary of about 35 rows, which is pretty big, I think. You can see these parameters by going to the Network panel -> XHR -> Headers -> Query String Parameters. I was wondering if the `param` dictionary really needs to contain all of the Query String Parameters, and if it doesn't, how do you know which ones are *needed* and which ones aren't?

Answer (score 0):

There is no generic answer, because it's entirely website-specific. You may try&fail, try&fail until you get a list of required parameters. Or, you may stop thinking about it, by using a real browser.

Example (using [`selenium`](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.org) and headless `PhantomJS` browser):

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait


driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()
driver.get("http://fplstatistics.co.uk/Home/Events")

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "myDataTable")))

for title in driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("div[style*=underline]"):
    print(title.text)
```

Prints:

```
Player Price Changes
Player Status Changes
```

Comment: I figured out that the only required parameter is `iDisplayLength`, but I have another question. Say I want to get the all changes made on the 5th of October, I can set `iDisplayLength` to 30 for example, so I guarantee (I don't there'll be more than 30 changes in 1 day, so it's not really a guarantee, but practically is) it includes all the changes made on the 5th of October, and then filter out the ones that weren't. But how would I go about just getting the updates made on the current date? Any ideas?